# Why did this character matter in Endgame?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Because it is the 1 out of over 14 million futures in which the Avengers won, you would expect that all of the surviving named characters would play a role that no one else could do, so they were integral to the plot in one way or another.

Tony for example:

> had the biggest part to play, from perfecting the time travel to being the one to use the stones to wipe Thanos and his forces out.

But even characters with less important roles still mattered.

Captain Marvel:

> Rescued Tony from space.

Rocket:

> Was the one who figured out Thanos' location at the start of the movie, allowing them to go after him.

Nebula:

> General knowledge about Thanos, the location of the Soul and Power stone, and her second(?) self was important in getting Thanos and his army to the battle that they lost.

Natasha:

> Died to get the Soul stone, and organised everyone and kept them together for the five years.

Scott:

> Provided the basis of time travel.

And so on, everyone seemed to play a specific role that no one else could really have done, however I cannot think of anything in particular that the following character did, which another character could have done themselves:

> Rhodey

What did they do that means they needed to survive the snap?

Comment: What did Bucky do? What did the rest of the billion people do? WHo said unsnapped people had purpose to serve?

Comment: The character mentioned in the OP survived the snap, and went with Nebula during the trip.

Comment: Rhodey knocked Quill out with one punch, and was instrumental in locating Hawkeye by tracking him around the world while Natasha co-ordinated everyone else

Comment: I had forgotten about the organisation of everyone in the first five years by Natasha, that's pretty specific. But knocking someone out isn't very specific, and I don't recall how he in particular was necessary to track Clint?

Comment: You survived the snap. what did you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> you would expect that all of the surviving named characters would play a role that no one else could do, so they were integral to the plot in one way or another.

### There's no evidence of this

There is nothing to indicate that specific characters were "spared" to be integral to the resolution of the Infinity Crisis.

Certainly, **most** perform some *specific* action which one could argue helps with the plot but that's by no means indicative that they *specifically* had to perform that action.

Strange saw 14m+ outcomes but there is NO indication of what was specifically required for the ONE successful outcome **except**, possibly, for Tony's sacrifice.

It's possible that Rhodey's contribution, assuming he was required to *anything*, was knocking out Quill, or possibly just saying the right thing at the right time....or coming up with a suggestion that the team followed.

Can we point to it and say "That's the one thing"? - No, but that doesn't mean it didn't happen.

Comment: Yeah, stupid question since it's based on speculation that because this was the one timeline they won, everyone had to have played a significant part, but that isn't necessarily true. My bad.